# How can I make one field of an array of objects equal to false with _lodash ? sim

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a simple javascript array of objects. Each object has a field called `current` which can be true of false.

Is there a way that I can make every one of those objects `current` field equal to false with javascript or with _lodash ?

Comment: `objects.forEach(function (object) { object.current = false; });` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array.forEach(function(object) { object.current = false; });
```

or, if `forEach` is not present, such as on an ES3 implementation:

```
for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; ++i) {
    array[i].current = false;
}
```

or, with [`_.forEach`](http://lodash.com/docs#forEach) in Lo-Dash

```
_.forEach(array, function(object) { object.current = false; });
```